# Handlebars is not defined error with package livestamp-hs

Tags: meteor

I am using the package `livestamp-hs` in my Meteor app. This works fine, except in the console I see the error message: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined`, which is caused by this package (helpers.js):

```
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Handlebars.registerHelper('livestamp', function(timestamp) {
      return new Handlebars.SafeString('<span class="livestamp" data-livestamp="'+ timestamp  +'"></span>');
    });
}
```

I checked `package.js` of this package to see if handlebars is being used, and as far as I know this is OK:

```
Package.on_use(function(api) {
    api.use(['jquery', 'handlebars'], 'client');

    api.add_files(['moment.min.js', 'livestamp.min.js', 'helpers.js'], 'client');

});
```

Although this is not a big problem on localhost, it causes an infinite loop when deploying to either meteor.com or heroku.com. Any ideas to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Meteor 0.8, the `handlebars` package was replaced by the `ui` package. You'll want to use that in your `package.js` file to ensure that you pull it in.

`Handlebars.registerHelper` still works, but `UI.registerHelper` is the new syntax.

On another note, livestamp is last decade's way of creating updated timestamps. I recommend the Meteor-based way to use time on the client, which is reactive and synced to server time: https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync. (Disclaimer: I maintain that package.)

Comment: When I user ``UI.registerHelper``, it returns ``UI is not defined``?

Comment: If I want to use something like ``5 minutes ago`` with your package, how can I do that? Do you have an example for me? Thanks!

Comment: Got it, I need to change this ``api.use(['jquery', 'ui'], 'client');`` in ``package.js``. Now it works

Comment: @John you'd combine it with moment.js formatting. See https://meteor.hackpad.com/Meteor-Cookbook-Using-Dates-and-Times-qSQCGFc06gH.